# Define the relation $R$ so that $xRy$ if and only if $x+4y$ is dividable with $5$

Tags: relations

> We define the relation R on the set 
>   $A=\{
>  -8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
>  \}.$
>
> so that $xRy$ if and only if $x+4y$ is dividable with $5$.

Ok so how should i define this $R$ with $x$ and $y$?

Should I try with every element = $x$ and with every element = $y$? Is not that very many combinations to consider?

Comment: Hint: x+4y is dividable with 5 if and only if x-y is dividable with 5. Does this help you?

Comment: Well yes I  guess you mean that I only need to check for 0-8?

Comment: So if i pick x = 0, do i then try with the formula for y = 0-8?  Then pick x = 1 y = 0-8... That's like 9*9 combinations to try? :P

Comment: As @ArseBerk explained in his answer R is an equivalence relation. So you just need search for at most 5 classes of equivalencies in A.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $5|(x+4y)$ if and only if $x \equiv y \mod 5$. Then can you find the (equivalence) classes (if you did not learn about it, you can try to find the elements which are equivalent modulo $5$)?

As an example, $\{-5,0,5\}$ is one of the classes because $-5 \equiv 0 \equiv 5 \mod 5$. There are four more such classes and when you find them, you are basically done because you know that $x \equiv y \mod 5$ so $x$ and $y$ should be chosen from the same class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? :P

Comment: Maybe I can add one more hint which makes it easier to continue.

Comment: Yeah please do :)

Comment: As I understand it I pick x = 0 then using the formula for y = 0-8. Then i pick x =1 and y=0-8 and so on. So i need to check 9*9=81 different combinations of x and y?

Comment: Not really. If you pick an arbitrary $x$, then you can add/subtract $5$ to find the equivalent elements ($x-5, x+5$, etc.) without checking everything. Can you see why?

Comment: Hmm well if I add/subtract 5  to an arbitrary  that  then gets me another element in the set, I guess you mean that that element is dividable by 5 or something?

Comment: No, if $x = 1$ for instance, adding/subtracting $5$ will still give you an element with remainder $1$ when divided by $5$. So they will be in the same class. If $x$ is divisible by $5$, then adding/subtracting $5$ will also yield an element that is divisible by $5$ as well.

Comment: −6≡-1≡4 **and** −5≡0≡5 **and** −4≡1≡6 **and** -8≡−3≡2≡7 **and** -7≡−2≡3≡8 ? How do i translate these to R?

Comment: You can either write $R$ instead of $\equiv$'s by using transitivity of the relation you have or, since a relation is nothing but a set, you can use set notation such as $R = \{(x,y)\in A\times A\ |\ x \equiv y \mod 5\}$.